# Get an Element inside an Iframe and Assign a Value to it using java script

Tags: javascript

I am using an User Control/Html Editor in which there is an Iframe, since I can't change the  value of it from javascript directly, I want to just append a text in the Iframe's body tag.

The Problem is I can get the Iframe element but how can I get it  tag? also how can I write a text to it?.

For Example: The Iframe looks something like this:

```
<iframe>
<html>
<body>
----Here I want to write a text-----
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using vanilla JS only:

```
var iframeElt = document.getElementById('myIFrameId'),
    iframeDocument = iframeElt.contentDocument ?
        iframeElt.contentDocument : iframeElt.contentWindow.document,
    iframeNewDiv = iframeDocument.createElement('div');

iframeNewDiv.innerHTML = 'some new content here';
iframeDocument.body.appendChild(iframeNewDiv);
```

Using jQuery (which will eliminate any cross-browser issues) (**untested**):

```
$('#myIFrameId body').append('<div>some new content here</div>');
```

Because of security restrictions imposed by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), **the iframe must be in the same domain as the parent page** for either of these to work.

Comment: IE's 6-8 don't support `.contentDocument`, you have to use `.contentWindow.document`.

Comment: @Andy: thanks, updated. I can't usually be bothered to write my own browser-specific code...

Comment: I dnt want to create a new div element I want to append text in a body :(

Comment: Also the body is coming null :(

Comment: @BreakHead: which browser is `body` null in? Your question is not clear - are you trying to replace **all** of the text in the iframe body?

Comment: I am using FireFox, iframeDocument.body is always null

Comment: No, I just want to append the Text in <body> tag

Comment: @BreakHead: it works just fine for me in FF 3. **Is the iframe in the same domain as the page it's embedded in?** If not, you **cannot** manipulate the page in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World!'));
ifrm.document.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have an iframe which looks like this:

```
<iframe id="theID"> ... </iframe>
```

and inside the iframe, you have an element which looks like this:

```
<div id="insideID"> ... </div>
```

Using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$('#theID').contents().find('#insideID').html('This is the inner HTML you want to change');
```